# How to use signal between different modules

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I know how to use signal in a module or class like this:

```
 class A (QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def afunc (self, i):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("doSomePrinting(int)"), i)    

    def bfunc(self, i):
        print "Hello World!", i
        sys.exit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    a=A()
    QObject.connect(a,SIGNAL("doSomePrinting(int)"),a.bfunc)
    a.afunc(10)    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I don't know how to use signal between different modules, for example:
a.py and b.py .I define and bound signal in a class of a.py ,and I want emit the signal to call the bound slot which define in a.py in b.py.

I use this way:

> self.logsignal.connect(self.handle)  signalMange.signal =
>   self.logsignal

I use a class to store the instance in a.py and I call it in b.py like this:

> signalMange.signal.emit('start write project...')

What about my way? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a.py"
The class A has a signal called my_signal and we have defined a method_for_signal in our class.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class A(QObject):
    my_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__():
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.name = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM"

    def method_for_signal(self):    
        self.my_signal.emit(self.name)
```

"b.py"

Here the class A is imported in class B, where we want to our signal.

```
from a import A
class B(QObject):

    def __init__():
        super(B, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def update(name):
        print str(name)

    def signal_connect(self):
        self.obj = A()
        self.obj.my_signal.connect(B.update)
```

The signal_connect method of class B when invoked will make our signal give the desired output.

Comment: More like `from a import A`

Comment: I can't understand all.where to invoke method_for_signal? in the signal_connect()?@Juna

Comment: you can connect method_for_signal to a pushbutton's clicked event for example ...suppose on click of your pushbutton in user interface, you want this signal to be emitted.@CinderellaM

Comment: It create a instance of A in class B,and it need self.obj to invoke method_for_signal().so It can be used only in class B.Do I think right?@Juna

Comment: no... the method_for_signal -- method is of class A and this method you need to connect to pushbutton's clicked event in your user interface. Whereas the signal_connect method is of class B....and you need to connect this method to some event of class B related user interface.

Comment: I get it .Thank you!!

Comment: I have another question need you help,What about my own way?I use a class as a namspace to store the bound signal,If I want to invoke the boud signal ,I extract it from the class.@Juna